# Groupby Array elements in Mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb

I have an array element in my DB and I want to group By and calculate the number of repetitions of different elements in this array. assume following collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   tags: ['SQL', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
},
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902d)
   title: 'NoSQL Overview', 
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'PHP'],
}
```

I want to calculate the number of repetitions of different elements in tags field such as mongodb, database, noSQL in this collection.
How can I solve this problem in mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- counts the repetitions in all the collection
- unwind to make each tag in seperate document
- group by tag, and count the repetitions

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oG2eUf7EE1N)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$tags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$tags",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "tag": "$_id",
      "count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Wow it works. thank you so much. It is a little complicated for beginner :)

Comment: can you give me a good reference to exercise these things ?

Comment: no its very easy, `$unwind` looks scary at start, but its not, read mongodb documentation its very good

Comment: [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) its the reference with all the operators with examples, see the pipeline stage operators to find the $unwind

Comment: excuse me, I have another question. I added a new filed with name created_at (for example , created_at: 2021-10-03 10:05:51.755Z) and I want to categorize these calculations based on time for example hot hashtags on last hour or today. how can I categorize your query based on time?

Comment: create a new question if you can, with sample data in, and expected data out. Seems like you will need `$hour` to get the hour from the date, and then group by tag + hour, 2 fields in group.

Comment: I created a news question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424221/groupby-array-elements-and-categorize-them-based-on-date-in-mongodb-query