# Groupby Array elements and categorize them based on date in Mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb

I have an array element in my DB and I want to group By and calculate the number of repetitions of different elements in this array based on different datetime. assume following collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   tags: ['SQL', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   created_at: 2021-10-03 10:05:51.755Z
},
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902d)
   title: 'NoSQL Overview', 
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'PHP'],
   created_at: 2021-10-03 14:05:51.755Z
},
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902d)
   title: 'Developing', 
   tags: ['java', 'btc/usdt', 'PHP'],
   created_at: 2021-10-03 14:05:51.755Z
}
,
{
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902d)
   title: 'databases for search', 
   tags: ['elasticsearch', 'database', 'PHP'],
   created_at: 2021-10-03 12:05:51.755Z
}
```

I want to calculate the number of repetitions of different elements in tags field such as mongodb, database, noSQL based on datetime (for example hot hashtags in last hour, today or this month) in this collection. How can I solve this problem in mongo?

```
expected answer like . 
1 - hot hashtags in last hour ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
2 - hot hastags in last 5 hours : ...
3 - today : ...
4 - this month : ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- not calendar based, based on difference on milliseconds
- keep only last 30 days data
- facet and 4 group by
- its exactly the same code 4x
  The only difference is the multiply

  - last 30days : `(now_date-created_at) <= (* 30 24 60 60 1000)`
  - last 24h : `(now_date-created_at) <= (* 24 60 60 1000)`
  - last 120 hours(5days) : `(now_date-created_at) <= (* 5 60 60 1000)`
  - last 60 min : `(now_date-created_at) <= (* 60 60 1000)`
    *subtraction works on dates also, and returns milliseconds
- filter the date depending on what we want its 4 different filters
- unwind
- group by tag and count occurences
- sort by count
- limit 2 to keep like the 2 top hotttest tags, you can change it to any value, like limit 1 to keep only the hottest tag

*if you want calendar based like 3 October(3 days data only), query must be changed, the same is for day(query is for 24 hours) etc (in those cases we should use `$hour` `$month` etc)
Its not big change in query.

```
   //same month
   {"$eq" : [ {"$month" : "$$NOW"}, {"$month" : "$created_at"} ]
   //same day(assuming same month from previous filter)
   {"$eq" : [ {"$dayOfMonth" : "$$NOW"}, {"$dayOfMonth" : "$created_at"} ]
   //same hour
```

*we could also use the new `$dateTrunc` to check for same month etc.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZAz2ZCdSGo)

(Query is big but its the same thing 4x)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "created_at": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$created_at"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$tags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$lte": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$$NOW",
              "$created_at"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$multiply": [
              30,
              24,
              60,
              60,
              1000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "month-tag": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$lte": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$$NOW",
                    "$created_at"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    30,
                    24,
                    60,
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "count": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "tag": "$_id"
          }
        }
      ],
      "day-tag": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$lte": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$$NOW",
                    "$created_at"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    24,
                    60,
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "count": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "tag": "$_id"
          }
        }
      ],
      "5hour-tag": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$lte": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$$NOW",
                    "$created_at"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    5,
                    60,
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "count": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "tag": "$_id"
          }
        }
      ],
      "hour-tag": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$lte": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$$NOW",
                    "$created_at"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    60,
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "count": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 2
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "tag": "$_id"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: WOW. I wish I could give you more than 1milion badget. it was so great. a complicated query. it is a nice education for learning writing query in mongo . thank you so much :)

Comment: ok good it helped, just be carefull with those difference, because its not calender based, for example for october that has 28 days, you cant do those, but here its not month based, its 30 days difference,24h*5 difference, 24h difference etc. Its not hard to change to be also same month/same day/same hour but this query doesnt do this.

Comment: yeah but i think if we examine last 30 days (not last month) it would work. Am I right? the other point is how should I save datetime format to achieve this goal better? because inserting data is my duty and I can save date field any way I want

Comment: we have many functions for those for example [month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) we have for day of month, hour of day, we have many. You could save those, but saving just the date, and calculate each time , i dont think it costs alot.